# Working with JSON and a multidimensional array (JS)

Tags: php, jquery, json, multidimensional-array

I've got the following issue: I wrote a search function which results are being saved into an array. As i handle the response of that function with the [jquery form plugin](http://www.malsup.com/jquery/form/), i created an additional array which is filled with all of the arrays created by the search. Then, i want to parse that multi-array to my jQuery script as a JSON object. So far so good, but how do i make the multi-array accessable to the script? (Like multiarray.array1.property)

Here is my code so far:

- [HTML / JS]

> ```
> <!DOCTYPE html>
> <html> 
> <body>
> <div class="edit">
> <h2>Editieren</h2>
> <form id="suchen" method="post"><input type="text" id="search" name="id">
> <input type="submit" value="Senden"></form>  
> </div>
> </html>
> ```

​

```
    $('#suchen').ajaxForm({

    url: "./php/search.php",
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data){

        alert(data[0]) ;

    },
        clearForm: true
}) ;​
```

- [PHP](http://codepad.org/3hzO85X1)

Thank you in advance

Edit:

Example of JSON:

```
{
    "id": "33",
    "firma": "sls",
    "strasse": "Industriegebiet Siebend",
    "plz": "66663",
    "ort": "Merzig",
    "vorname": "",
    "nachname": "Ruf",
        "email": "ronny.ruf@web.de ",
    "bemerkung": "",
    "partner": "",
    "kinder": "1",
    "nation": "D",
    "betreuer": "Adam",
    "anrede": "Herr"
}
```

Comment: Could you provide a sample of the generated JSON?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At your PHP

```
       while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){

                    $article = array (

                        "id"=>$row['id'],
                        "firma"=>$row['firma'],
                        "strasse"=>$row['strasse'],
                        "plz"=>$row['plz'],
                        "ort"=>$row['ort'],
                        "vorname"=>$row['vorname'],
                        "nachname"=>$row['nachname'],
                        "email"=>$row['email'],
                        "bemerkung"=>$row['bemerkung'],
                        "partner"=>$row['partner'],
                        "kinder"=>$row['kinder'],
                        "nation"=>$row['nation'],
                        "betreuer"=>$row['betreuer'],
                        "anrede"=>$row['anrede'],

                     ) ;
                    $hits[] = $article;
        }

                    echo json_encode($hits) ;
```

At your jquery...

```
$('#suchen').ajaxForm({

    url: "./php/search.php",
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data){
       $.each(data, function(i, val){
           console.log(val); /*alert don't work on arrays*/
           alert(val.firma); /*you can alert some array key for example*/
       });    
    },
        clearForm: true
}) ;​
```

I replace alert with console.log because val will be array...
to access any of its keys just write val.keyname..

as .. `alert(val.strasse);`

Comment: Thank you, but it seems i am doing something wrong.
Accessing a keyname won't work, it says undefined when i try it as you wrote above. Also, i do not understand how to switch between the arrays.

Answer (score 0):

`parseJSON` helps you

```
var data = jQuery.parseJSON('{"name":"John"}');
alert( data.name );
```

Comment: why don't you use `JSON.parse`