# JSON Response Multidimensional Array

Tags: php, arrays, json, multidimensional-array

Hello i got a JSON response that looks like the one below. I want to count the posts that are younger then 24 hours and also check for unique user urls:

```
{  
   "meta":{  
      "network":"all",
      "query_type":"realtime"
   },
   "posts":[  
      {  
         "network":"facebook",
         "posted":"2014-08-16 08:31:31 +00000",
         "sentiment":"neutral",
         "url":"someURL",
         "user":{  
            "name":"Terance Podolski",
            "url":"someURL",
            "image":"someURL"
         }
      },
      {  
         "network":"facebook",
         "posted":"2014-08-16 08:30:44 +00000",
         "sentiment":"neutral",
         "url":"someURL",
         "user":{  
            "name":"Łukasz Podolski",
            "url":"someURL",
            "image":"someURL"
         }
      },
      {  
         "network":"facebook",
         "posted":"2014-08-16 08:25:39 +00000",
         "sentiment":"neutral",
         "url":"someURL",
         "user":{  
            "name":"Marcin Podolski",
            "url":"someURL",
            "image":"someURL"
         }
      }
]
}
```

Thanks in advance.

With the help of @Elias Van Ootegem i got my problem solved. The code looks like that:

```
// Json Reponse decodieren
$jsonArray = json_decode($jsonData);



function getMentionsFromLast24H($myArray){
    // set variable exactly one day ago
    $since = new DateTime('-1 day');

    // array where to store timestamps in
    $recent = array();

    foreach ( $myArray -> posts as $post ) {

        try {
            $post -> posted = new DateTime (substr ( $post->posted,0,19 ) );//create DateTime instance
            if ( $post -> posted >= $since )
                $recent[] = $post;//add to array
        } catch ( Exception $e ) {
            echo $e -> getMessage();
            exit(1);
        }

    }

    return $recent;

}

$mentions24h = count(getMentionsFromLast24H($jsonArray));

print_r($mentions24h);
```

Comment: Can you share with us what you have tried?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Working with JSON and a multidimensional array (JS)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13289339/working-with-json-and-a-multidimensional-array-js)

Comment: Your question isn't related to JSON. Just php multidimensional arrays

Answer (score 3):

It's pretty simple, really: decode the json data, compare the `posted` values with time - 24 hours, if the value is great than time-24 hours, add it to an array. That's it, you'll end up with an array containing all posts that were added in the last 24 hours:

```
$data = json_decode($jsonData);//creates object
$since = new DateTime('yesterday');
$recent = array();//this is the array we'll be constructing
foreach ($data->posts as $post)
{
    $post->posted = new DateTime($post->posted);//create DateTime instance
    if ($post->posted > $since)
        $recent[] = $post;//add to array
}
var_dump($recent);//this is the array you're after
```

That really is all there is to it.

Comment: with that i got a array (size=0)
  empty

Comment: @fabu_baracus: In which case, there are no posts since yesterday

Comment: when i try using your example the loop dosen't seem to loop. is it possible that i have to use two loops inside each other, because of the multidimensional array???

Comment: @fabu_baracus: If the response truly looks like the example you show here, then no: the array of posts is found in `$jsonDecodedData->posts`, each element of this array is an instance of `stdClass`, and its timestamp is found under the property `posted`. Note that the data you posted here lists posts that are older than 1 day (08/16 is 2 days ago)

Comment: if you're using the code I posted here, that should've been `json_decode($jsonData)`, without the second parameter (`true`), and the function is called `json_decode`, not `jsondecode`... you _can_ keep decoding the data to an array, but replace the property accessing bits by array indexes (`foreach ($data['posts'] as $post)` instead of `$data->posts`). Also ensure the variable containing the json string is actually called `$jsonData`

Comment: so after adding a try catch i get this error log: DateTime::__construct(): Failed to parse time string (2014-08-16 08:31:31 +00000) at position 25 (0): Unexpected character

Comment: @fabu_baracus: Because the date is in an unrecognized format, change `new DateTime($post->posted);` to `new DateTime(substr($post->posted,0,19));` (only pass the bit that is formatted as _"Y-m-d H:i:s"_, the `DateTime` object can work with that just fine. but you'll loose the timezone bits, so look into a way of fixing that